# Find failed requests and queries that go into deadlock

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Some of the requests to my application fail every day. I want to know every time which all queries went into deadlock.

I am running MySQL 5.6 on AWS.

FYI, tool suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: please provide detail of queries and server log file

Comment: I am away from machine. Working on mobile. Will do as soon as possible. Also, I am not looking a tool that would tell me which queries are creating a deadlock or any table as a matter of fact.

Comment: You must check for errors after every statement!